# Running the DBT2 test results in 0.00 NOTPM

Tags: mysql, benchmark

I'm trying to run the MySQL [DBT2 Benchmark Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html), I have unzipped the [archive](http://downloads.mysql.com/source/dbt2-0.37.50.3.tar.gz) and run the following commands:

```
./configure --with-mysql
make
make install
mkdir /tmp/dbt
datagen -w 3 -d /tmp/dbt --mysql
scripts/mysql/mysql_load_db.sh --path /tmp/dbt --mysql-path /usr/bin/mysql
scripts/run_mysql.sh --connections 20 --time 300 --warehouses 3
```

But got the following output:

```
...

Stage 3. Starting of the test. Duration of the test 300 sec
STARTING DRIVER COMMAND:   /root/dbt2-0.37.50.3/src/driver -d 127.0.0.1 -l 300 -wmin 1 -wmax 3 -spread 1 -w 3 -sleep 300 -tpw 10 -outdir /root/output/14/driver -p 30000 -warmup 0 -cooldown 20 -intermediate_timer_resolution 0
Shutdown clients. Send TERM signal to 5154.
Shutdown driver. Send TERM signal to 5190.

Stage 4. Processing of results...
                         Response Time (s)
 Transaction      %    Average :    90th %        Total        Rollbacks      %
------------  -----  ---------------------  -----------  ---------------  -----
    Delivery   0.00          N/A                      0                0  100.00
   New Order   0.00          N/A                      0                0  100.00
Order Status   0.00          N/A                      0                0  100.00
     Payment   0.00          N/A                      0                0  100.00
 Stock Level   0.00          N/A                      0                0  100.00

0.00 new-order transactions per minute (NOTPM)
0.0 minute duration
0 total unknown errors
0.00 rollback transactions
0 second(s) ramping up

scripts/run_mysql.sh: line 632:  5154 Killed                  nohup $CLIENT_COMMAND > $OUTPUT_DIR/client.out 2>&1
scripts/run_mysql.sh: line 632:  5190 Killed                  nohup $DRIVER_COMMAND > $OUTPUT_DIR/driver.out 2>&1
Test completed.
```

During the execution, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` did show that 20 clients were connected, all sleeping.

Any idea why no transactions are executed?

Comment: since no one else wants to take the question, I'm going to go through the same steps on a clean centos install using whatever MySQL 5 comes with 6.4.

Comment: any output in $OUTPUT_DIR/client.out or $OUTPUT_DIR/driver.out 2>&1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done the following to reproduce the output you are seeing from dbt2.

1. Installed Centos6.4
2. Installed MySQL 5.1.69 via YUM
3. Installed [Innotop](http://code.google.com/p/innotop/) to view in real time all queries and open transactions

Ran the bench as you did:

```
[root@centos-cef dbt2-0.37.50.3]# scripts/run_mysql.sh --connections 20 --terminals 5 --time 300 --warehouses 3 --verbose
```

Innotop only showed 20 active clients but no open queries or transactions

DBT2 provides several logs. On the system I used for testing, there was a main directory /root/output and then a number for each execution.

/root/output/N where N is the execution number.

In the file **/root/output/3/client/error.log**, I found the following information

```
Tue Jul 30 16:57:23 2013
Microseconds : 998724
tid:-1511446784 mysql/dbc_payment.c:32
mysql reports SQL STMT: stmt ERROR: 1305 PROCEDURE dbt2.payment does not exist
Tue Jul 30 16:57:23 2013
Microseconds : 998753
tid:-1511446784 mysql/dbc_common.c:97
ROLLBACK INITIATED

Tue Jul 30 16:57:28 2013
Microseconds : 859693
tid:-1511713024 mysql/dbc_new_order.c:88
mysql reports: SQL: call new_order(2, 5, 984, 1, 9, 90056, 2, 8, 47872, 2, 3, 48592, 2, 7, 21925, 2,                                 7, 96574, 2, 5, 53239, 2, 8, 30640, 2, 4, 39619, 2, 10, 86015, 2, 8,                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                          0, 0, @rc),  ERROR: 1305 PROCEDURE dbt2.new_order does not exist
Tue Jul 30 16:57:28 2013
Microseconds : 859735
tid:-1511713024 mysql/dbc_common.c:97
ROLLBACK INITIATED
```

I'm seeing **ROLLBACK INITIATED** throughout the log. I am also seeing that certain stored procedures are not installed such as **dbt2.payment**

So I looked a little further and there is another script that has to be run in order to create the stored procedures in the dbt2 database.

```
scripts/mysql/mysql_load_sp.sh --database dbt2 --client-path /usr/bin/
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Load SP: delivery
Load SP: new_order
Load SP: new_order_2
Load SP: order_status
Load SP: payment
Load SP: stock_level
```

Have you run

```
scripts/mysql/mysql_load_sp.sh --database dbt2 --client-path /usr/bin
```

on your server to load in the stored procedures?

After loading in DBT2's stored procedures, I ran DBT2 again and this time I did see transactions in Innotop's output

```
[RO] InnoDB Txns (? for help)                             localhost, 2h7m, InnoDB 1s :-), 765.68 QPS, 22/0/0 con/run/cac thds, 5.1.69

History  Versions  Undo  Dirty Buf  Used Bufs  Txns  MaxTxnTime  LStrcts
      6       102  0 0       1.56%     99.80%    21       00:00         

ID   User  Host       Txn Status  Time   Undo  Query Text
217  root  localhost  COMMITTED   00:00     0  COMMIT
```

I noticed though as you did, that DBT2's output was still showing O's everywhere, so I increased the number of warehouses to 30. My thinking was that there wasn't enough transactions or activity to generate useful results

```
scripts/run_mysql.sh --connections 20 --time 300 --warehouses 30 --verbose

Stage 4. Processing of results...
                         Response Time (s)
 Transaction      %    Average :    90th %        Total        Rollbacks      %
------------  -----  ---------------------  -----------  ---------------  -----
    Delivery   3.32      0.004 :     0.001          136                0   0.00
   New Order  44.59      0.027 :     0.095         1826             1654  90.58
Order Status   4.20      0.002 :     0.001          172                0   0.00
     Payment  42.86      0.007 :     0.014         1755                0   0.00
 Stock Level   3.57      0.010 :     0.000          146                0   0.00
```

And as you can see, DBT2 sent back appropriate results this time.

Comment: The missing stored procedures was indeed the problem. This is curious though, as the *README* says "optional, only if you ran `configure` with `--enable-mysql-sp`". One of the stored procedures had a field too short as well, resulting in many rollbacks (`out_w_city` in the `payment` SP). Fixed this, and it now works.

Comment: @Benjamin - definitely enjoyed working on this question. It was the various logs and files in /root/output that lead to the solution.